# Joomla Microdata doesn't show headline and image

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, schema.org, microdata, google-rich-snippets

With the Google Structured Data Testing Tool, I analyzed an article made with Joomla 3.4 and T3 framework and despite that imposed the image and show the title tells me always:

> headline: Missing
>   image: missing

What options do I need to enable to show these microdata based on schema.org?

Comment: It's really hard to know without seeing your layouts.

Comment: I think the problem is in T3 template. In fact it does not mention the word "headline" and "image" of meta tag of microdata section

Comment: @user2582575 Google's Structured Data Testing Tool appears to have made both headline and image properties required recently (it was not the case last month). Unless you can directly add your own code you would need to pass this onto Joomla as a bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solutions is to manually add a microdata code into php template for article. This work's!